# Combining stacked bars and total line

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, anaconda

I had some code that would produce a nice stacked graph and a total line when given a `DataFrame`. when I upgraded my Anaconda to 4.0 (pandas 0.18, matplotlib 1.5.1) the total line stoped being produced. I can't seem to figure out why.

Here is some test code that worked originally.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

td = pd.util.testing.makeTimeDataFrame(10)
fig = plt.figure()
td.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True, ax=fig.gca())
plt.plot(td.sum(axis=1),'k-',label = 'Total')
```

Currently this just leaves the barplot but does not add the line.[image: Stacked bar no Total :(]

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

td = pd.util.testing.makeTimeDataFrame(10)
ax = td.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
ax.plot(ax.get_xticks(), td.sum(axis=1), label='Total')
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

[image]

pandas/matplotlib doesn't seem to like the (slightly) different axis/index after each operation. If you create just the bar plot, you'll notice that the axis defaults to datetime values, whereas if you create just the line chart, the axis will default to date values. This seems to cause some underlying confusion, thus requiring you to be explicit with `ax.get_xticks()`.